# How to find the following probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm currently preparing for my test and I have stumbled upon a question which I am not sure how to solve. The question is as follows:

> A test consists of 40 multiple choice questions to each of five
>   possible answers given,only one of which is the correct answer. The
>   student is asked to select the correct answer to each question. The
>   first twenty questions (Section A) earn two marks each for the correct
>   answer and the remaining twenty questions (Section B) earn three marks
>   each for the correct answer. These two sections of the test are based
>   on different and unrelated course material. All wrong answers earn
>   zero marks (there is no negative marking). Consider a student who has
>   not studied for the test and who answers each question by guessing.
>
> (a) Find the probability that the student obtains exactly 70% of the
>   marks in each of the the two sections.

This looks like a Binomial Distribution to me with `n=40`, `p=0.2` and `q=0.8`. My working is to find that `Pr(x=0.7)`. I tried that and the answer was wrong. Can anyone please explain to my why this working resulted in the wrong answer?

Thanks

Comment: The numbers of correct questions  in both sections are binomial distributed as follows:  $X=Y\sim Bin(20,0.2)$ Then you have to calculate $P(X=14)\cdot P(Y=14)$

Comment: Note that the question specifies that the student must get $70\%$ of each part right.  Thus, he must get $14$ right on each part.

Comment: Btw, what was your work in detail? The result is a small number due the words "exactly" and "each". What is the given solution?